# Rotating a point using Math.Asin()

Tags: c#, geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to rotate a point around the origin, and I've seen other ways to do this but I still don't understand why my original code doesn't work properly.
here is the original algorithm I constructed.

```
        decimal[] values = new decimal[] {5.6, 2.4, 8.7};
        decimal hypotenuse = (decimal)Math.Sqrt((double)(values[0] * values[0]) + (double)(values[1] * values[1]) + (double)(values[2] * values[2]));
        decimal x = values[0] / hypotenuse;
        decimal y = values[1] / hypotenuse;
        decimal z = values[2] / hypotenuse;
        decimal checkerhypotenuse = (decimal)Math.Sqrt((double)(x * x) + (double)(y * y) + (double)(z * z));
        values[0] = (decimal)Math.Sin(Math.Asin((double)x) + (double)RotationX) * hypotenuse;
        values[1] = (decimal)Math.Cos(Math.Acos((double)y) + (double)RotationX) * hypotenuse;
```

values is a collection of x, y, and z coordinates for my points. and instead of giving back results, it isn't rotating properly.
RotationX is the amount in radians that the rotation should change around the origin.

The concept of this is if Sin(Arcsin(theta)) = theta, then Sin(Arcsin(theta) + additional degrees of rotation)
checkerhypotenuse should always equal 1, and it appears to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approach (corrected) may work in 2D case:

```
    cx = values[0] / hypotenuse;
    cy = values[1] / hypotenuse;

    values[0] = (decimal)Math.Cos(Math.ACos((double)x) + (double)RotationX) * hypotenuse;
    values[1] = (decimal)Math.Sin(Math.ASin((double)y) + (double)RotationX) * hypotenuse;
```

But in 3D case your x,y,z are [direction cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine), and `Math.ACos((double)x)` **does not** give right angle in OXY plane.

For example:

```
values[0] = values[1] = values[2] = 1
```

Definitely projection of point onto OXY plane lies at angle 45. But direction cosine is `1/Sqrt(3)`, not `1/Sqrt(2)`, so rotation by -45 with your formula does not provide zero coordinate.